# Rescue GRUB problem 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7

I have a problem with starting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a system which has a Windows 7 beside.
the GRUB cannot load and we see a massage which announces there is a problem with GRUB and there is a line like :

```
grub rescue >
```

I can load the system with a GRUB recovery CD,but the loaded GRUB knows the other OS as a Windows Vista.
How can I fix it and have my two OS without needing CD.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the wiki entry below and see whether it fixes the issue.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[See this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169108/windows-7-pro-wont-load-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-lts/195013#195013) my answer will work for fixing your problem but You must need Ubuntu Live disc.